# remove animation data from geometry nodes tree

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I've unfortunately keyframed some values in a geometry node tree to show some of its capabilities, but now I don't know how to delete them. I've tried in the NLA and the Dope Sheet Action Editor, but I can't select the keyframes for a node group.

[image]

I can go through it manually, but is there a way to remove all animation data in the node group?